# iMac keeps crashing on render

Tags: imac, video, crash, kernel-panic

**Problem:**
I have a iMac 2019 27-inch and when I try to render a video in Final Cut Pro or Davinci Resolve there could be happening 3 things:

1. Mac crashes completely, restarts and shows a kernel panic.
2. Final Cut Pro or Davinci Resolve crashes.
3. The video renders fine.
   But the weird thing is that there is no consistency, on week this works completely fine and the other time it doesn't.

**What have I done to try fix it?**

1. Reinstalled macOS 2 times, doesn't do anything.
2. Did a diagnostic check for hardware problems, result: the iMac said that there are no hardware problems.
3. Reinstalled Final Cut Pro or Davinci Resolve.
4. Tried rendering on a clean system (only Final Cut Pro or Davinci Resolve) also sometime a crash.
5. Contacted Apple support: couldn't help me.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

**iMac specs**

- CPU: Intel Core i9 8-Core 3.6 Ghz
- GPU: Radeon Pro Vega 48 8 GB
- Ram: 128 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- MacOS: 13.1 (22C65)

Comment: Kernel panics usually point to faulty hardware. I’d start by looking at RAM.   Try removing half, then test. If it persists, try swapping the other half in.

Comment: Oke, i will try that, but the weird thing this that I got the iMac from my that and he had no problems with it.

Comment: Components fail plus the previous owner may not have pushed it as hard. A bad memory module that was never accessed will make your system appear trouble free until you access it.

Comment: Could possibly be heat-related if not RAM. Rendering for sure ramps up the machine as fast as it will go. If you suspect that, getting iStat Menus & artificially ramping the fans up to full might prevent it. I do that with mine, even though it doesn't crash, seeing the CPUs so hot makes me slightly nervous so I put the fans on full until it's finished.

Comment: Please provide the relevant panic and crash reports (found in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`) by uploading to www.PasteBin.com and appending the links to your original post.

Comment: Additionally, please also try running an extended memory test: Download the free version at https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm and `dd` the `memtest86-usb.img` image onto a flash drive, then boot from it. Apple Diagnostics often misses errors that MemTest86 catches so run that and see if you get any errors (it'll take a while!).

Comment: @pion Really thank you for recommending memtest. I found out that one of my ram sticks gave errors. I a now testing if my iMac doesn't crash without the bad ram stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, I suggested two parallel tracks of investigation:

1. Reviewing panic & crash reports in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` for initial clues.
2. As Apple Diagnostics is often insufficient for identifying memory hardware errors, I recommended using [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) to run a more thorough memory test than the one you first performed.

While we haven't seen data from #1 yet, your run of MemTest86 indicated a DRAM failure. You're now isolating the DRAM module from the system. In all likelihood, you have found the root cause of, and solution to, your continual crashes.